# Update a custom column of sales_flat_order table after order complete in magento

Tags: php, xml, magento, magento-1.9

I have a custom column used in `sales_flat_order` in my code and I just want to update a column value of this table when the order is complete. I have used the event `sales_order_save_after` and below is the code:

```
public function salesOrderSaveAfter(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    $orderId = $order->getId();

    $Incid=$order->getIncrementId();

    if ($order->getState() == Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE) {
        $con=Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
        $write=$con->getConnection('core_write');
        $query= "update `sales_flat_order` set `vorder_payment_state` = 2 where `entity_id`='.$orderId.'";
        $write->query($query);
    }
}
```

But, unfortunately the column value is not getting updated.

Comment: try `sales_order_save_commit_after` event observer.

Comment: I'd add some logging to see if your observer is firing when it's supposed to be.  You should just be able to call `$order->setVorderPaymentState(2)->save()` (if you adjust your obsever to only be called once.  Alternatively, you could listen for `sales_order_invoice_save_after`

Comment: Executing query like that is very wrong. You should use Magento ORM. If you use different event, one triggered before order is saved, you could simply do `$order->setVorderPaymentState(2)` which would update the order attribute with almost no overhead.

Comment: I have tried both the ways, the value is not changing neither from magento ORM nor sql queries. And yes, my observer is firing and logging the data. When I write the same output query in database sql, it works just fine.

Comment: Using direct queries in observer is not acceptable. Use Magento ORM it should work

Answer (score 1):

You can try with:

```
if ($order->getState() == Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE) {
    $order->setVorderPaymentState(2);
    try{
       $order->save();
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
       Mage::throwException($ex->getMessage());
    }
}
```